# How does PubSub / SQS FIFO achieve exactly-once delivery?

Tags: locking, distributed-computing, google-cloud-pubsub, messaging

Reading through https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/cloud-pub-sub-exactly-once-delivery-feature-is-now-ga?hl=en, I came across the following statement

> Exactly-once delivery eliminates this situation. Due to the introduction of the data deduplication layer, Pub/Sub knows that there is an outstanding delivery#1 which is unexpired and it should not deliver the same message to this subscriber (or any other subscriber).

Now I am wondering, how would such a data deduplication layer prevent this? Ma naiive assumption would be:

1. Try to save delivery lock record with message id and expiration in database
2. If successful, send message
3. Delete when message was acknowledged

But I already see problems:

1. Database lock record saved and application crashes without delivery. Now retry must wait for the delivery lock record to expire. Consistent, but long delay.
2. Database lock record saved and application hangs right before the send statement. Another process gets the lock and sends the message. Process 1 recovers and executes the send statement. Now we have 2 messages send, violating the guarantee google gives in that doc.

So how would a data deduplication layer solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question.

1. Like most large scale distributed systems, this comes down to a trade off. In this case, the occasional high tail-end latency is part of the trade-off for exactly once delivery.
2. For the given example, the guarantees [provided](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery#exactly-once_delivery_guarantees) by the feature would ensure that the first delivery can't be successfully acknowledged (or lease extended). That's a signal that the service can use to identify another delivery for the same message. Using the [supported client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery#recommended_client_library_versions) will significantly reduce the odds of such a behavior with automatic lease management. Please note that "Exactly once side-effects", as called out in the blog post you have linked, isn't part of the guarantees.